# Migrating from RxJava2 to Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to migrate my code from RxJava2 to Coroutines. But I'm not sure how to achieve that.

For example, this is my old code to insert a code into the Room Database:

```
fun insert(note: Note) = Single.fromCallable {
        dao.insert(note)
    }.subscribeIn({ id ->
        note.id = id
        if (note.bitmap != null) update(note)
    }
```

**Note:** This code is in an object called DataHelper, which contains all the methods and the Dao object.

This is the Dao Call:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(note: Note): Long
```

Trying to replace that code with coroutine calls isn't clear, as I can't call a suspend function from the main thread.

```
fun insert(note: Note) {
        val id = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            dao.insert(note)
        }
        note.id = id
        if (note.bitmap != null) update(note)
    }
```

`dao.insert()` is now a suspend function in the Dao.

Making the `insert(Note)` function a suspend function means I have to call it with a Dispatcher from any place (E.g, a fragment). Which either means there has to be a Dispatcher in every fragment or activity, or having the whole line of calls suspended.

What is the right way to run background threads with Coroutines?

Comment: If you don't want to make `CoroutineContext` of every **activity/fragment** then use `GlobalScope` to call your function in insert method, although it's not best practice to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use suspended functions in your Room Dao:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insert(note: Note): Long
```

Whenever you want to access/call this Dao method, you'll need `CoroutineScope` to do that.

**Method 1** Use **GlobalScope:**

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    dao.insert(note)
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
     // main thread calls here, e.g. updating view, showing toast, etc
    }
}
```

**Method 2** Create a `CoroutineScope`:

```
val job = SupervisorJob()
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)

scope.launch {
    dao.insert(note)
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
     // main thread calls here, e.g. updating view, showing toast, etc
    }
}
```

> Note: When your instance (e.g. Activity/Fragment) is destroyed, you
>   can call: `job.cancel()` to cancel your coroutine jobs.

**Method 3** : You can extend your class with `CoroutineScope`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob()

    ....

    fun onSomeAction() {
        launch {
            dao.insert(note)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                // main thread actions
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using `ViewModel` for calling dao methods, then you can use `viewModelScope` extension:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    dao.insert(note)
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
     // main thread calls here, e.g. updating view, showing toast, etc
    }
}
```

Unlike other options, `viewModelScope` will be auto cancelled when `onCleared()` method of `ViewModel` is called.

To use this option you need to include this dependency in your **app** level `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01"
```

Comment: In Method 3 I believe you can simply do `CoroutineScope by CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)` and avoid having the `override val coroutineContext...`. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#coroutine-scope and also https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md#structured-concurrency-lifecycle-and-coroutine-parent-child-hierarchy for more. Note that if you want to cancel execution in `onDestroy()` you need to manually call `cancel()`.

Answer (score 2):

In you example fun insert should be a suspend function:

```
suspend fun insert(note: Note) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            dao.insert(note)
        }
        //note.id = id
        //if (note.bitmap != null) update(note)
    }
```

and then from your ViewModel use viewModelScope:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
            noteRepository.createNote(note)
        }
```